# Client-side, then() or other?

Tags: dart, dart-async

How i can use "Future" in client-side ?

And, how I can block the execution of my code, while no event is catch ?

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';

Map data;

Future<String> ft_get_pseudo()
{
  InputElement button;
  InputElement text;

  text = querySelector('[name="pseudo"]');
  button = querySelector('[name="push"]');
  button.onClick.listen((_) => text.value);
}

void    main()
{
    WebSocket wss;
  String encode;

  data = new Map();
    wss = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:4040/ws');
  ft_get_pseudo().then((name)
  {
    data['pseudo'] = name;
    encode = JSON.encode(data);
    wss.onOpen.listen((_) => wss.send(encode));
    wss.onMessage.listen((msg) => print("Msg received : ${msg.data}"));
  });
}
```

I saw Promise function in ecmascript 6, there is a way to use it, or the idea ?

**HTML :**

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="application/dart" src="client.dart"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Client</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="console">
</div>
<input type="text" name="pseudo" size="20" placeholder="pseudo">
<input type="button" name="push" value="Send">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not able to comprehend what you try to accomplish. You can't block execution. You can register a callback where the execution should continue when an event occurs.

Comment: I want send the socket only when we put the button. Here, then() is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this, but I don't yet fully understand what you try to accomplish.
Can you please just add a comment what you need differently?

```dart
Map data;

void main() {
  //(querySelector('[name="push"]') as ButtonInputElement).onClick.listen(btnClickHandler);
  (querySelector('[name="push"]') as ButtonInputElement).onClick.first.then(btnClickHandler);

  // this would work too, because every element has the click event.
  // querySelector('[name="push"]').onClick.listen(btnClickHandler);
}

void btnClickHandler(MouseEvent e) {
  String name = (querySelector('[name="pseudo"]') as TextInputElement).value;    

  data = {'pseudo': name}; 
  String encode = JSON.encode(data);

  WebSocket wss = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:4040/ws');
  wss.onOpen.listen((_) => wss.send(encode));
  wss.onMessage.listen((msg) => print("Msg received : ${msg.data}"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get text.value from the ft_get_pseudo() function when you push on the button, right? If so, you need to create a [new Completer](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#dart-async.Completer) and return its Future at the end of the ft_get_pseudo(). Then, in the button's onClick event, you just complete the future with the value of text.value.

Code might be something like this:

```dart
Future<String> ft_get_pseudo()
{
  Completer _completer = new Completer();

  InputElement button;
  InputElement text;

  text = querySelector('[name="pseudo"]');
  button = querySelector('[name="push"]');
  button.onClick.listen((_) => _completer.complete(text.value));

  return _completer.future;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For such a simple use case you can do it this way

```dart
Future<String> ft_get_pseudo()
{
  return new Future(() {
    InputElement button;
    InputElement text;

    text = querySelector('[name="pseudo"]');
    button = querySelector('[name="push"]');
    button.onClick.listen((_) => _completer.complete(text.value));
  }
}
```

Comment: @RastislavLamoš if the use case is that straight-forward you can use this simpler code.

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer. Didn't know about that feature before.

Comment: It's not working like I want. Actually, it's going in "then()" while I didn't push the button. So, that's sending a NULL value to my server.